# Javascript files not loading for page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a fairly simple HTML file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>deploy.rb</title>
        <script src="test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="OtherScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        body
    </body>
</html>
```

test.js looks like this:

`window.onload = function () { alert("It's loaded!") }`

Can someone tell me why I don't get an alert when the page loads? (and why none of the functions in OtherScript.js are executing)

[The full contents of the html file can be found here, if it helps.](http://pastebin.com/MuZMak22)

Comment: Hit F12 and look in the console and network tab

Comment: check if the `src` is correct

Comment: the `window` must start with a capital

Comment: Check the JS console. If the scripts are not found, then you will see an error. Also, it might be showing an error in your code that it´s preventing its execution. So. It could be either the scripts are not reacheable, or they have some sort of error.

Comment: @SiddharthNand — It must not. JavaScript is case sensitive and `window` is all lowercase.

Comment: Also. Are you opening the HTML file locally in your browser, or is there a server like apache or nginx there?

Comment: could you just call `alert` not inside of `onload` function?

Comment: @Quentin thanks for tell me

Comment: did the console have any error messages?

Comment: try putting the `type="text/javascript"` before the `src`

Comment: @SiddharthNand No offense, but blind guesses aren't helpful. There's nothing wrong per se with the code in the question.

Comment: @mplungjan test.js shows up in both the sources and network tabs.

Comment: @AsierPaz There are no errors in the console.

Comment: Can someone tell me why my question is being voted down, and how I can improve it?

Comment: @AsierPaz I'm loading the file directly in my browser i.e. `file://`

Comment: @SiddharthNand  that is not necessary- he should rather delete it.

Comment: Any errors in the console? It is likely the lack of such information that make people vote down

Comment: @mplungjan agreed. We need to see some code. Matter of fact, try to create a new javascript file with just this content: "console.log('hello world');" without double quotes and import just that script into your page. Then load the page and check if the javascript console gives you the output. (In chrome, CTRL + Left Shift + I, then Console)

Comment: I created a new script (test-2.js) as you said, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot. OtherScript.js also used `window.onload`. I consolidated both scripts into the same file, and now it works file.

Answer (score -2):

you might check the directory structure.  The code looks fine to me, so if I had to guess the .js files are not being found correctly.  If they're in the same directory as the HTML file you might try appending `./` to the beginning of the filename.

Comment: This is a comment. It will likely be voted down. Please answer real questions to build more than the 50 rep needed to comment